# Reuse old transform with new Java update?

Tags: group-policy, groups

We just started deploying Java through GPO.  Currently have Java 6 update 23 being pushed out and I would like to move to update 25.  Do I need to recreate the transform for each update or can I just apply the old transform to the new .msi?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'll answer my own question.  I tried reusing the transform from update23 and it did NOT work (none of the changes were applied).